# loading CSS based on page location

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit of trouble finding out how to do this but let me explain. I am building a webpage and I have a fixed header at the top but I want to load different content into it based on how far you have scrolled down the page. Ideally I want to load both pictures and text into preset areas of the header. so maybe like conditional CSS or what ever can get me this effect. does anyone here have any ideas??? I have this so far:

var titles = [
    'Pick 1 "Quote here"',
    'Pick 2 "Quote here"',
    'Pick 3 "Quote here"',
    'Pick 4 "Quote here"',
    'Pick 5 "Quote here"',
    ''
];

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var pos = $(this).scrollTop();

```
if(pos < 1025) {
    $('.title').slideUp().text(titles[0]);
}
if(pos > 1026) {
    $('.title').slideDown();
}
if(pos > 2000) {
    $('.title').text(titles[0]);
}
if(pos > 2250) {
    $('.title').text(titles[1]);
}
if(pos > 3575) {
    $('.title').text(titles[2]);
}
if(pos > 4800) {
    $('.title').text(titles[3]);
}
if(pos > 6000) {
    $('.title').text(titles[4]);
}
if(pos > 8000) {
```

Comment: so i found this here this i can work with to modify my text but can i use this method to load pictures too? [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/6386w/)

Comment: this too [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KEjfe/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may modify your first sample code to say

```
if(pos < 200)
{
    $('.top').slideUp();
}
if(pos > 200)
{
    $('.top').slideDown().text(titles[0]);
    $('.top').css("background-image", "");
}
if(pos > 700) 
{
    $('.top').css("background-image", "url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3javascript.gif')");
    $('.top').text(titles[1]);
}
```

Comment: another question I have, is instead of targeting a scroll location can I target a div or object for the greater then or less then if statment???

Comment: like if i wanted to say if pos => "#slideTitle1" do x. is that posible

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes.  You would just have to convert the "#slideTitle1" into an integer value before doing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling and general messing around I came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KEjfe/2148/):

```
$("#body").scroll( function() {
var divtop =  $("#largebody").offset().top;
if ( 1 > divtop)
    $("#header").css("background-image", "url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3javascript.gif')");
else
    $("#header").css("background-image", "");
});
```

It seems to work ;). Some notes:

- the offset().top gets the distance between the top of the browsers screen and the associated div. So you want your change if this equals 0. I took the value of 1, because it would swap earlier instead of changing when your content "leaves" the top of the browser.

I removed my old answer because this one is better

Comment: but i don't know the syntax to make that variable work, but yes it would be great if I could target a div not a pixel value

Comment: so i have six divs to target i should make a var for each and then is statments for the six like "if (2 > middlediv)" "$(#middlediv).css". and do i need to use a else's and just if's or if then else else else else and else?

Comment: so the 1 is like you setting a 1px buffer between the top of the div and the screen?

Comment: The 1 is the position from the top of your browser where the div has to be to trigger the events. In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/KEjfe/2149/ the image would change earlier, when the div is 101 px from the top of the screen. Just try different values in the example and you ll see what I mean ;).

Comment: ok i learned alot from that but this is something more kin to what i need to do http://jsfiddle.net/KEjfe/2150/ but the thing i cant seam to fix is that i cant find out how to remove the image after scrolling all the way down then back up?

Comment: You probably should use "else if" instead of if, but this would not change anything about what the result of the code will be. You could also write line 6 and 7 shorter like:   $("#header").css({"background-image": "", "background": ""});    Both suggestions are optional changes. Anyway it seems like you got it working ^^.

Answer (score 0):

how about using wow.js works also fantastically with animate.css

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: i dont think animation is what i am doing with this project